# Limit number of occurances in output group-by sql query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this query

```
select rep, companyname,count(companyname) as [count], Commission from customers
group by repid,companyname,Commission
```

It returns lets say

```
rep    companyname     count    commision
1       ABC              1        10%
2       XYZ              2        10%
2       XYZ              1        20%
3       JKL              4        10%
3       JKL              1        30%
```

Desire output is

```
rep    companyname     count    commision
2       XYZ              2        10%
2       XYZ              1        20%
3       JKL              4        10%
3       JKL              1        30%
```

I would like to have an output so that I show the only those companies who are repeated twice or more in the result. How do I modify the above query. I made the query simple (remove where clause).

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand what you want from the query.
You say you would like the company name repeated twice or more, by this do you mean if there is a count of 2 you want to see the two records for that company listed? If the count is 4 you want to see all 4 records for that company?

Comment: I think we can not put a condition on the output of a query. So this would not be possible.

Comment: @Dave: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will match your requirements. I couldn't think of a way of doing it without some sort of sub query or CTE:

```
select 
    rep, companyname, [count], commission
from (
    select 
        rep, companyname,count(companyname) as [count], Commission,
        count(1) over (PARTITION by companyname) as [companycount]
    from customers
    group by repid,companyname,Commission
) sub
where companycount > 1
```

Comment: Thanks but getting error over `where companycount > 1`. I guess we cannot run a query against a sub-query which has group by clause in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a subquery to get the non-unique company names like this.

```
select rep, companyname,count(companyname) as [count], Commission from customers
where companyname in (
  select c1.companyname from customers c1
  group by c1.companyname having count(*) >= 2
)
group by repid,companyname,Commission
```

Comment: I did that it returns of count(companyname) which you see 2,1,4,1. I want a condition if the name is repeated twice or more. count(*)comes from the database not from the output of query.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I've edited the answer to show a different solution.

Comment: Don't think this works still - you need to count the number of occurences in the result set, not in the original data.

Comment: @Tim: I think your query is correct, but only if `(repid,companyname,Commission)` is a unique combination in the table.

Comment: And that is probably not the case, as then the `GROUP BY` would not be needed.

Comment: @ypercube True - I saw `companyname` as being the key column for detecting a unique company. Maybe `rep` is, in which case substitute that in the query :)

Comment: This query did work but returned all result, not what I wanted (twice or more occurrences of companyname). The top most query did work for me so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
select rep
     , companyname
     , count(*) as [count]                  --- equivalent to count(companyname)
     , Commission
from customers c
where exists
      ( select *
        from customers c2
        where c2.companyname = c.companyname 
          and ( c2.repid <> c.repid
             or c2.Commission <> c.Commission 
              )
          and ( extra-conditions )
      )
  and ( extra-conditions )
group by repid, companyname, Commission
```

Comment: +1: That's another way of looking at the problem - just check for rows that will create a separate result set based on the group by criteria.

Comment: For the record, this query did not work. I dont see the condition btw `and [count] >=2`

Comment: @Dave: If you have extra `WHERE` conditions, these would need to be put both in the query and in the subquery.

Comment: I translated `[count] >=2` to: There `EXISTS` another row with same `companyname` but different `repid` or different `commission`.

Comment: well, It still returns non-duplicate companies. The first query works nicely for me though.

Comment: @Dave: Do your `extra-conditions` have any `OR`?

Comment: I dont have any extra conditions. and I removed `c2.repid <> c.repid
             or ` which is not needed.

Comment: @Dave let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2501/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dave)

Answer (score 0):

Add a HAVING clause after your group by, e.g. HAVING count(companyName) > 1

Comment: note my `count` column which is the same as count(companyname) and see my desired output. I tried this before I posted the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `HAVING` keyword, which is essentially a `WHERE` condition for your `GROUP BY`

```
select rep, companyname,count(companyname) as [count], Commission from customers
group by repid,companyname,Commission
having count(companyname) > 1
```

Comment: see my comments above. I generated the count column just to see what having was working on as it did not returned the desire results.

Comment: @Derek: This will not get what the OP wants.